# Multiple "Set StartUp Projects" Configurations

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I have a big solution and for debugging purposes I have to start many Projects by using "Set StartUp Projects" Feature of Visual Studio 2012. However often I need to change what projects I need to start (Sometimes is Project A,B,C, sometimes Project B,C,D etc.)

Does someone knows such an Extension?

Comment: no idea about an extension, but afaik this is saved in the .suo file so you could swap them arounf for having different configurations?

Comment: @gsharp, yes, you are right.  I've deleted my comment. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx) further explains.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Take a look at the [SwitchStartupProject extension](https://heptapod.host/thirteen/switchstartupproject). (I'm the author)

Since version 2.0, it allows you to configure multiple multi-project startup configurations. You can switch between the configurations with a toolbar dropdown box:

[image: Select startup projects from dropdown]

To configure two configurations (A, B, C) and (B, C, D):

- Install the extension (you might need to restart VS)
- A new `Startup Project` dropdown box appears to the right of the `Start` button.
- Click on it and choose `Configure...`
- Select single-project list mode `None` (to hide the single project items from the dropdown)
- Add two configurations and name them `ABC` and `BCD`
- Add multiple projects to each of the configurations
- Choose the order in which the projects will be started

Note: Unlike the Visual Studio startup projects dialog, the extension does not allow you to choose `start without debugging` for a project. So all projects that you add to a multi-project startup configuration are started with debugging.

Comment: Grüezi Andreas. Amazing tool! Exactly what I was looking for :)