# Setup C# solutions startup projects in a configuration file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution with 4 projects in it. I wish to start them all.

For example, I had somebody new clone by work. This means that startup projects wouldn't be configured. However what I want is a file that defines what startup projects should be set when you run for the first time.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question - but maybe this can help you further? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543360/multiple-set-startup-projects-configurations?rq=1

Comment: Sadly not, basically, I'm looking for a way to configure the startup projects of a solution either via command line or with a config file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found this information is written by Visual Studio to `*.suo` file in `.vs` directory that Visual uses to store some user solution settings and options.

Maybe you could develop Visual Studio extension that could persist selection of start up project. You can find some information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-user-options-dot-suo-file?view=vs-2019).

More about `.suo` file in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227448/what-is-actually-contained-in-a-suo-file).

Answer (score 0):

Solution explorer > "yourcoolprojectname" right click> properties> common properties> multiple startup project> choose projects

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of how to do it in VS. Currently trying to automate the process for other developers.

Comment: @John_Mason27, maybe you simply agree among developers to follow up instruction file when cloning repository? Such file can be added to projects in source control and contains  instructions written in words. Not everything can/should be automated.

Comment: I agree with that, just seeing if there is a way to do this. As then my companies projects can be installed and setup to develop on a new machine by running an exe 

Comment: I Understand now .Maybe you should package your project with docker compose. I don't know if there is any other way.@John_Mason27